# Unable to show mysql database on a basic Django based website

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnm8f6Wavk to work on creating a basic dynamic website. 
I managed to create and test for the database on the mysql server. But I'm unable to reproduce that data on the webpage. Following are the codes for files I had to edit:

The views.py file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from blog.models import posts
def home(request):
 entries = posts.objects.all()[:10]
 return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : entries})
```

The url.py has the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

The models.py file has the following code

```
from __future__import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class posts(models.Model):
 author = model.CharField(max_length = 30)
 title = models.Charfield(max_length = 100)
 bodyText = models.TextField()
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

The settings.py has the following database for input:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'Firstblog',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '3305',
    'HOST': '', 
    'PORT': '',
}}
```

I have edited the html file to say :

```
 <title>A BASIC WEBSITE</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1> Firstblog </h1>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
    {{entry.title}}
    <h3> Posted on {{ entry.timestamp }} by {{entry.author}} </h3>
    <p>{{entry.body}}</p>
```

The output I get when I run the above is just "FirstBlog" as the header but no database issued entry.The video is pretty old so I had to make a lot of changes to it. Since I'm new to django, I'm quite unsure on how to proceed forward with this. I currently have python 2.7.12(anaconda custom x86-64) , and django 1.10
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variables in the template are called 'posts'

```
<h1> Firstblog </h1>
    {% for entry in posts %}
        {{entry.title}}
        <h3> Posted on {{ entry.timestamp }} by {{entry.author}} </h3>
        <p>{{entry.body}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection name is "posts", no "entries"

Try this:

> {% for entry in posts %}